# Troubles in sockets

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, java-server

When I started the server and client, the server can't receive the words typed in client.
I hope the server show the messages from the client. But the server seemed hanging on the "bf.readLine()". I don't know why...
following the codes...

Server code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(11111);
System.out.println("current port:"+ss.getLocalPort());
Socket s = ss.accept();

System.out.println("remote port:"+s.getPort());

BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

while(true)
{
    String str = bf.readLine();
    System.out.print(s.getPort()+": ");
    System.out.println(str);
    if ("bye".equals(str))
        break;
}
```

and then the client code:

```
Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",11111);
System.out.println("connected to remote server:"+s.getPort());
System.out.println("My port:"+s.getLocalPort());

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true)
{
    System.out.print("I said: ");
    String l = in.next();

    pw.write(l);
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println("Echo~~~~"+l);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing bytes with write(), but reading with readln(). Readln requires a "\n" at the end.

Comment: Try using [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).println(l).

Comment: @PiggyZhu, In short, change `pw.write(l);` to `pw.println(l);`